# How to add "irrelevant" edges

Tags: graphviz

I have this graph:

```
digraph G {
1 [label="car"];
2 [label="x"];
3 [label="car"];
4 [label="y"];
5 [label="cdr"];
6 [label="cdr"];
7 [label="cons"];
8 [label="x1"];
9 [label="x2"];
10 [label="cons"];
11 [label="y1"];
12 [label="y2"];
13 [label="f"];
14 [label="f"];
15 [label="car"];
16 [label="cdr"];
17 [label="car"];
18 [label="cdr"];
1 -> 2;
3 -> 4;
5 -> 2;
6 -> 4;
7 -> 8;
7 -> 9;
10 -> 11;
10 -> 12;
13 -> 2;
14 -> 4;
15 -> 7;
16 -> 7;
17 -> 10;
18 -> 10;
}
```

and I want to add these other edges:

```
1 -> 3 [style="dashed"];
2 -> 7 [style="dashed"];
3 -> 8 [style="dashed"];
4 -> 10 [style="dashed"];
5 -> 6 [style="dashed"];
6 -> 9 [style="dashed"];
7 -> 10 [style="dashed"];
8 -> 11 [style="dashed"];
9 -> 12 [style="dashed"];
13 -> 14 [style="dashed"];
15 -> 8 [style="dashed"];
16 -> 9 [style="dashed"];
17 -> 11 [style="dashed"];
18 -> 12 [style="dashed"];
```

but without altering the layout.
I tried setting the edge weight to 0, but it doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can simply add

```
edge[constraint=false];
```

before adding the *irrelevant* edges.

Without:

[image]

With the edges:

[image: graphviz non layout altering edges]

(There still seem to be some small changes)

Comment: to avoid even this small change, one could add all the edges even in the first version, but with `style=invis` for the dashed edges, so those won't be visible